# Can a weller EC2002m base use other weller solder irons?

Tags: soldering

HI all,
 I was wondering if a Weller EC2002m base use other Weller soldering irons and/or soldering fingers? I am finding it hard to find tips for my EC1201A soldering iron and would like to switch to a better soldering iron to facilitate better tip selections.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://bama.edebris.com/download/weller/ec2002m/EC2002M_OI_PL.pdf) is a document with a list of the hand pieces compatible with the EC2002M.

Comment: The original ink has died, but the file seems to available [here](http://bama.edebris.com/manuals/weller/ec2002m/).